# Values of the normal of a selected face

Tags: python, normals

I need to be able to find the normal of a selected face (given that we are in edit mode), or be able to compare the position of the face to the origin of the object. I have no idea how to start either of these things because I'm new to blender python scripting. With any advice you already have my thanks.

Comment: I assume you need the face normal, not the vertex normals? Please also only ask one question at a time. Comparing the origin to the face position is something different.

Comment: @aliasguru, I know that it was two questions, but as I was searching for the answer for one, I didn't know whether or not it was possible. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll need to :

```
import bpy
```

Then get the object you want :

```
obj = bpy.context.active_object #The active object
obj = bpy.data.objects['Cube'] #The object by its name
```

Then for the object information :

```
obj.location #Object position rotation, scale
obj.rotation
obj.scale
```

Object faces are in data.polygons :

```
p = obj.data.polygons[0]
p.select #Indicates if the face is selected
p.normal #The face normal
p.vertices #The vertices indexes
```

The vertices and their positions :

```
vIndex = p.vertices[0] #Index of the vertex from the face p
v=obj.data.vertices[vIndex] #The corresponding vertex object
v.co #Its coordinates
```

It can be a good way to learn how to navigate through the objects hierarchy using the Python console and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd> for auto completion and discover the object properties (in complement to the documentation) :

[image]

Comment: so question is the face normal something like a vector. Does it just have 3 float values?

Comment: @TheShadowblast123, the normal is a 3D vector yes

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all, does it? The question was about accessing face normals.

Comment: @foobarbecue, This answer is more giving advice about a way to learn how to access Blender data in Python, because the OP asked about normals but not only in the question. Though faces normals access is given in the line "p.normal". But if needed, feel free to provide another answer.